How Send the SMS using AWS End User Messaging
We have set up AWS End User Messaging on AWS for sending SMS. In this setup, we created a phone pool, a configuration set, and a protection configuration. However, I'm unsure how to use these settings in PHP code with the AWS SDK.
I tried using the AWS SDK with Amazon SNS, but it only allows setting the SenderID in the configuration, not the OriginationNumber. I attempted to set the attribute AWS.SNS.SMS.OriginationNumber to specify the origination number, but encountered an error: 'Message attribute names starting with 'AWS.' or 'Amazon.' are reserved for use by Amazon' when sending SMS.
I also tried setting the configuration set with the attribute AWS.SNS.SMS.ConfigurationSet, but I still received the same error.
Could you please help me understand how to send SMS using the AWS End User Messaging configuration?"
$messageAttributes = [
'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType' => ['DataType' => 'String','StringValue' => 'Transactional'],
'AWS.SNS.SMS.OriginationNumber' = ['DataType' => 'String','StringValue' => $originationNumber,],
'AWS.SNS.SMS.ConfigurationSet' = ['DataType' => 'String','StringValue' => $configurationSet]];

$result = $sns->publish([
    'Message' => $message,
    'PhoneNumber' => $phoneNumber,
    'MessageAttributes' => $messageAttributes
]);


Your endpoint is a little bit weired, it shouldn't be https://pinpoint.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/sms/messages ?

I have updated provided URL in curl command and hit from the command prompt but still received same Error.
